# Duplex Outlet's Max Amperage Rated by Socket or by Whole Unit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, outlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplex Outlet's Max Amperage Rated by Socket or by Whole Unit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/duplex-outlets-max-amperage-rated-by-socket-or-by-whole-unit)

If you have a duplex outlet thats rated for lets say 20 amps, is the whole unit rated for 20 amps, or is each socket rated for 20 amps?